# SQL Snowflake Min Date For Each Record & Group By Month

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, group

I am using Snowflake to get some information from the data. I have a table in which the same employee (PRS_ID) can be included in many rows and I want to take the EARLIEST date (BGN_DATE) for each employee (PRS_ID). Next, I want to see how many employees I have each month.

Ideally if I could have in YYYY-MM format (YYYYMM will work too). What I was working with is below:

```
SELECT PRS_ID, MIN(BGN_DATE), MONTH(BGN_DATE)
FROM myTable
WHERE EMP_STS = 'T' 
GROUP BY PRS_ID, MONTH(BGN_DATE)
```

However, this will show me the data per employee (PRS_ID), which is too granular (as explained above). But when I remove "PRS_ID" from grouping I get below error:

*SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 'myTable.PRS_ID' in select clause is neither an aggregate nor in the group by clause.*

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you

**Sample Data:**

| PRS_ID | EMP_STS | BGN_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| homsimps | T | 2022-01-30 |
| homsimps | T | 2022-02-28 |
| homsimps | T | 2022-03-30 |
| bartsimps | T | 2022-01-30 |
| bartsimps | T | 2022-02-28 |
| bartsimps | T | 2022-03-31 |
| lisasimps | T | 2022-04-30 |
| lisasimps | T | 2022-05-31 |
| lisasimps | T | 2022-06-30 |
| lisasimps | T | 2022-07-30 |
| margesimps | T | 2022-02-28 |
| margesimps | T | 2022-03-30 |

**Expected Outcome:**

| Period | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | 2 |
| 2022-02 | 1 |
| 2022-03 | 0 |
| 2022-04 | 1 |

Comment: the problem is the information for minim date and the colum for the count have no joining information. if ou wanted the number of employees for the month and year fromthe min date ok

Comment: Please update your question to show some sample data and the result you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using aggregation twice:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT PRR_ID, MIN(BGN_DATE) AS min_bgn_date
   FROM my_table
   WHERE EMP_STS = 'T'
   GROUP BY PRS_ID
)
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(min_bgn_date, 'YYYYMM') AS month, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cte
GROUP BY TO_VARCHAR(min_bgn_date, 'YYYYMM');
-- GROUP BY month
```

Comment: to avoid having to repeat the `TO_VARCHAR...` clause in the GROUPBY you can just refer to the position `1` or if there is no input columns called `month` you can use that with no problems also.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler function here, [`DATE_TRUNC`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/date_trunc.html) will allow you to convert dates to months. You can then convert to the format you'd like.

```sql
WITH MY_CTE AS (
    SELECT
        PRS_ID,
        DATE_TRUNC(MONTH, MIN(BGN_DATE)) AS MONTH_START
    FROM
        myTable
    WHERE
        EMP_STS = 'T'
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(MONTH_START, 'yyyy-mm') AS PERIOD,
    COUNT(PRS_ID)
GROUP BY 1
```